# How to switch between custom css layout and bootstrap css layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a little dropdown menu on my sample-page to toggle between a custom layout and a bootstrap layout. Is there a way to do this in javascript / jquery?

Comment: you can add specific classes to your dropdown and change them via jQuery e.g. with [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)
P.S.: pls look at [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a class (or more) in CSS that will contain your custom styles, then use jQuery to add or remove that class to / from the relevant element(s).

In jQuery, you can use the [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function for that.

CSS:

```css
.my-layout {
    /* do your custom styling */
}
```

JS:

```
$('#swap-layout').click(function() {
    $('#dropdown').toggleClass('my-layout');
});
```

Comment: TY, this helped me a lot, found a little example here too: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_toggleclass

Comment: One more question, do you know how to toggle a element, that already contains a class value? like this.. **css:** `.old {color: green;}`  **html:** `<p class="old">This is a paragraph.</p>`. So I can replace .old with .main?

Comment: give your element an `id` for easier identification, then use `$('#id').removeClass('old').addClass('main');` in jQuery...